# Which version of SmartStart supports HP DL120 G6?

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, hardware

Version 8.70 for example does not support it - minimum 120G7. So cannot reinstall Windows Server on the old G6 here...

Comment: v8.7 of SmartStart is, in fact, supported on that hardware platform (and offered as a download for all supported Windows versions on that platform).

Comment: @HopelessN00b - When using v8.60 and v8.70 of SmartStart there is the message displayed: "This model is not supported", after just booting or when trying to use "Install" options of SmartStart. Only "Diagnostics" works well (have not tried "System Erase").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are all of your [software and driver options](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdHome/?sp4ts.oid=3984622&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=lang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodNameId%253D3984622%257CprodSeriesId%253D3984621%257CswLang%253D8%257CswEnvOID%253D4064%257Caction%253DlistDriver&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) for Windows (assuming 2008 R2) on the HP ProLiant DL120 G6.

The server does not use a traditional SmartStart CD, but rather a model-specific "[Easy Setup CD](http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=3984622&spf_p.tpst=psiSwdMain&spf_p.prp_psiSwdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=lang%253Den%257Ccc%253DUS%257CprodSeriesId%253D3984621%257CprodNameId%253D3984622%257CswEnvOID%253D4064%257CswLang%253D8%257CswItem%253DMTX-9824e0c43e5049a9a1fbad32c2%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken)".

Comment: Yes, you are right. By the time I got this answer I already found  the note about "Easy Setup CDs" (apparently they come with the server, but are easily lost). It is rather silly to use a different CD/DVD for support of a subset of servers. Next they will start separating firmware DVD for DL and ML servers, or something like that...

Comment: The reasoning is that the HP 100-series servers do not have the same features as the 300/500/700-series. The 100-series servers are lower-end and are missing some of the management features. Note that they have a stripped-down IPMI LO100 versus a full ILO. There's enough difference in the platforms to justify these custom CDs.